# Which method is right to use React ref?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reference, components

I'm trying to use react refs. I've searched about this and I've found 2 way for implement refs.

Method one:

```js
constructor(props) {
  this.Modal = React.createRef();
}

<Modal ref={this.Modal} />
```

Method two:

```js
show() {
  this.refs.Modal.SHOW();
}

<Modal ref="Modal" />
```

The method one is through React.createRef and number two is simple way.

And I should say, those two methods work right ....

Thanks

Comment: string refs are discouraged.. it is legacy. Use the callback or the new `createRef()`. Check the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs).. also check [problems with callback ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#caveats-with-callback-refs)

Comment: don't use string ref, you cant use callback ref: ref={elm => this.Modal = elm}

Answer (score 1):

Your second method which uses string refs is legacy one and will be removed soon from `react` at all ([see more](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs)).

The first one - is available since [React 16.3](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs).

If you use `react` lower than 16.3 - please consider another method - [callback refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs).

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.modal = null;

  this.setModalRef = element => {
    this.modal = element;
  };
}

<Modal ref={this.setModalRef} />
```

Comment: @Mohammad if you have an ability to use `React` of version **16.3** or greater - you're free to use `React.createRef()`

Comment: @Mohammad if this answer helped you - actually it'd better to accept it as a correct one.